# Does a rational function extend to a point if all its 1-parameter extensions at that point agree?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f: X \dashrightarrow Y$ be a rational map where $X$ and $Y$ are varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ with $X$ smooth and $Y$ proper (or projective if necessary). Choose an open set $U \subset X$ on which $f$ is defined.

Pick a closed point $x \in X$ and an algebraic curve $C$ passing through $x$ such that $C \cap U \neq \emptyset$. Since the restriction of $f$ to $C$ can be uniquely extended to all of $C$ we may define $f|_C(x)$.

Let us say that all 1-parameter limits of $f$ at $x$ agree if there exists a point $y \in Y$ such that for *any* curve $C$ as above $f|_C(x) = y$.

Could anyone tell me if some variation of the following is true?

> If all 1-parameter limits of $f$ agree at $x \in X$ can $f$ be extended to an open set containing $x$?

One suggested alternative in case the first fails:

> Does $f$ extend to an open set $\tilde U \subset X$ if for all points in $\tilde U$ all 1-parameter limits of $f$ agree?

Comment: Yes, that is true, and you only need that $X$ is normal, not smooth.  This is quite close to the original formulation of Zariski's Main Theorem.

Comment: Also there was an extension to the seminormal case by Joe Ross, "A Characterization of Seminormal Rings".

Comment: @JasonStarr Could you please expand a little on how to use Zariski's Main Theorem to get this result? We don't have a birational morphism here, so I must be missing a standard trick.

Comment: You do have a birational morphism.  Let $U\subset X$ be the maximal Zariski open subset on which $f$ is regular.  Let $\Gamma_f:U\to X\times Y$ be the graph of $f$, which is a locally closed immersion.  Let $\widetilde{X}$ be the closure of the image of $\Gamma_f$.  Then the projection $\text{pr}_X:\widetilde{X}\to X$ is a birational morphism.  Via the valuative criterion of closedness, you know this morphism has finite fibers.  Now apply Zariski's Main Theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Jason Starr who answered my question in the comments. I would like to beef up his answer here for future reference.

> The answer to the first question--and thus for the second--is in the affirmative. In fact, there are no restrictions on the singularities of $X$; for instance it need not be normal let alone smooth.

Here is the proof:

**Step 1**

Let $U \subset X$ be any open subset where $f$ is defined, $\Gamma_U \subset U \times Y$ be the graph of $f$ and $\Gamma \subset X\times Y$ be the closure of $\Gamma_U$.

The restricted projection map $\pi: \Gamma \to X$ is proper, moreover it is an isomorphism over $U$. The goal is to show that $\pi$ is in fact an isomorphism over an open set containing $x$. By precomposing with this isomorphism we can extend $f$ around $x$.

To that end we will show that $\pi$ is quasi-finite of degree 1 around $x$.

**Step 2**

Let $\Gamma_x$ be the fiber of $\Gamma$ over $x$. Using the valuative criterion of closedness and the universal property of the fiber product it is easy to show that $\Gamma_x$ is in bijection with the set of values that appear as 1-parameter limits of $f$ at $x$.

The hypothesis states that this latter set consists of a single element. Using semi-continuity we conclude that in a neighbourhood of $x$, the fibers of $\Gamma$ consist of a single element.

Thus $\pi$ is invertible in a Zariski neighbourhood of $x$ and $f$ extends to this neighbourhood.